# Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /formatting.php

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, errors, formatting

I'm working on a WordPress site with Chinese language which use WP Bakery plugin.

I added woocommerce product category short code on home page to show some products from a category

It works on a all categories except one category.

when i add that category to show product it shows this error and products not showing

```
<b>Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in 
<b>/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php</b> on line <b>3797</b><br />
```

[image]
Anyone know a solution or reason for this error please.

Thank You

Comment: The error is likely because you `echo` an instance of the `WP_Error` class. But regarding how to fix it, you need to locate the code which triggered the error. And you should post it if you can't fix the problem..

Comment: @SallyCJ the function after <a href=" seems default woocommerce function to get an product url, i wonder why it works for some products and for some products shows this error, the url have English letters , i'll try to add that locations code here, Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the function being used there is the `get_term_link` function which returns a `WP_Error` instance when the term *does not exist*. So make sure you use the correct term name, slug, etc. But I could be wrong, since I don't know the code.